# Get name from cell for file name in Excell

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have a problem with the code below:

```
Sub SavePDF()

    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:="\\TERA\Rok\Leromik izdani računi\" & Range("B8").Value & ".pdf", _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=True

End Sub
```

I can't get name from cell B8 to my .pdf name.  I get the following error when it tries to save:

[image]

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: runtime error 1004, document not saved or open or there was error during saving.... something like that     if i put this line   Filename:="\\TERA\Rok\Leromik izdani računi\Export.pdf", _   than it works, but it always saves under name export.pdf

Comment: You need to add the full path: "DriveLetter:\Folder\SubFolder" & Range("B8").Value & ".pdf"

Comment: What value is in B8 ?  Is it a legal filename ?

Comment: @VBAPete - that is a full network (UNC) path, as indicated by the leading `\\\`

Comment: I have edited the question to include the error message that I assume you are getting.  (Delete it out again if it isn't the exact one you do get.)  Apart from answering Tim's question about whether B8 is a valid filename, are you sure that the file isn't open by someone else?  (You probably won't be able to replace a file that is already in use.)

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks, learned something new.

Comment: file is not oppened by someone else, in the middle of the night... :)     when i change line to this it works: Filename:="\\TERA\Rok\Leromik izdani računi\Export.pdf", _

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is an error when trying to open the PDF file after saving, sometimes after creating a PDF file something allows the PDF reader to stay open even when you have manually closed it. I have encountered this on many occasions when creating a PDF from a C# program in VBA.

This is the line where it will give you trouble. However, changing it to `False` will not help either.　Also, even if the filename is a perfectly legal name this error will occur.

```
OpenAfterPublish:=True
```

If you want to fix this, the below code will allow you to save the file to your destination and if there happens to be an open connection to PDF reader it will ignore the open after saving and just save to your selected location. So please be aware that the PDF file will not open after saving if this error occurs after using the below code.

Just add this, `On Error Resume Next`

```
Sub SavePDF()
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:="\\TERA\Rok\Leromik izdani računi\" & Range("B8").Value & ".pdf", _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=True

End Sub
```

Also, I prefer to save a file ensuring that I won't get the same file name, so make sure that the value in `Range("B8").Value` will never be the same will help a lot.